# Utilities.sleep still not able to provide enough of a break for Google Sheets function

Tags: javascript, function, scripting, google-sheets

I have a function to calculate a tiered bonus based on the number of sales:

```
function calculateBonus(sales) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  var output = 0;
    if (sales > 7) {
      output += ((sales -7) * 4);
      sales -= 7;
    }
    if (sales > 4) {
      output += ((sales - 4) * 3);
      sales -= 4;
    }
    output += sales * 2;

    return output;
}
```

However, even with the Utilites.sleep function it still produces an error.  The spreadsheet it is working in can contain hundreds of entries (currently in the low 400s). Is there a better way to optimize this so it will work?  Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you want a delay in this function.  What's the bigger picture here.  Where is this function being used?  Show us the code.

Comment: It's being used for a spreadsheet where there are hundreds of cells running it at the same time, this is resulting in an error because it's being called again too quickly.

Comment: Is this being used as custom cell formula?

Comment: Yes it is.  I'm trying to slow it down to let it function in all cells.

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet with us?  You may want to modify it by removing private info?

Comment: Now this is weird.  I went to modify it for sharing and it's functioning correctly with no errors telling me to insert Utilities.sleep().  I'll wait until tomorrow but it looks like it was just the time of the day I was running it or something.

Comment: Yes.  I've seen the same thing a couple of times.  I often just close the editor and the spreadsheet and reopen it and problems just magically disappear.  I would remove the sleep delay.  I would think it would make matters worse.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution was simply to reload the spreadsheet and it worked.  Right now I'm having no issues with the function, however this is something that has happened in the past and I'm not quite sure what causes it with simple functions such as this.